# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing one application in which my requirement is as below:

1. Login and create a webform through my application under test. It will generate one webform URL.
2. I am caturing the URL and opening a new tab by
   `driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"t");`
3. Now I am switching to window in which my webform is displayed.
4. Now I am navigating to the captured URL by using driver.get(URL);
5. Now it will open a webform (HTML form).
6. Now I am clicking on register button and it is capturing error message for required fields.(till here working fine)
7. Now if I try to enter name in a text box window is getting closed and below exception is getting captured:

   `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
   (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   Command duration or timeout: 165 milliseconds
   Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
   System info: host: 'BL2W3010159', ip: '10.205.34.33', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\S10C2~1.JAI\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7812_12384}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=53.0.2785.116, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
   Session ID: 8538a93785d4fd3ffcb5a1abb482a136
   Command duration or timeout: 925 milliseconds
   Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
   System info: host: 'BL2W3010159', ip: '10.205.34.33', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\S10C2~1.JAI\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7812_12384}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=53.0.2785.116, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=bb82bf2d-c736-40a0-9ddb-860b6720c0ce, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
   Session ID: bb82bf2d-c736-40a0-9ddb-860b6720c0ce
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:269)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:90)
   at com.executor.TestLibraries.NM.CampaignElement.webFormResponseAsAnAnonymousUser(CampaignElement.java:1610)
   at com.executor.Tests.NM.TestCampaignElement.createAWebformAndCaptureWebFormResponse(TestCampaignElement.java:576)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at Grid.ExecutorFactory.run(ExecutorFactory.java:243)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Comment: You need to read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as a matter of extreme urgency. What you have posted here makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback.I will try to improve in terms of asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

would you mind using **Google Chrome Driver 2.23**  instead? Even if exception occurs, if you try to catch the exception, ignore it, can you get further?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Chrome driver .exe as per the latest chromedriver found here and give it's path in https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",<Path of latest chromedriver.exe>);`